# Можно ли в Python через родительский класс получить доступ к методам дочернего?

Tags: python, классы, наследование

сообщество
Хотел узнать, можно ли каким-то образом с родительского класса получить доступ к методам дочернего?
Либо же, могу ли я каким-то образом сделать так, чтобы два дочерних класса имели доступ к методам друг друга?

У меня просто в проекте сейчас есть родительский класс и от него наследуются три хелпера. Хочу сделать так, чтобы либо родительский класс имел доступ ко всем методам всех трех хелперов(то есть своих детей), либо сделать так, чтобы эти три хелпера имели доступ к методам друг друга.
В идеале конечно первый вариант, но это наверное не реально, чтобы родительский имел доступ к методам дочернего.

Помогите, знающие люди!
Заранее благодарю

Comment: Зачем это вообще нужно? Почему вы решили применить именно наследование, а не три-четыре отдельных класса с композицией? Да и нужны ли вообще классы для хелперов, может их лучше отдельными функциями сделать?

Comment: Dima, пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: Если дочерний класс переопределяет какой-то из методов родительского класса, то при вызове этого метода из родительского класса будет вызываться переопределенный метод

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо тебе огромное, добрый человек. 
Не использовал композицию, потому что не знал о ней((( Теперь знаю, очень удобно и лаконично получилось. Спасибо!!